# segmentation fault in my code in bison-generated parser

Tags: segmentation-fault, bison, flex-lexer

I am tring to build a calculator which can do bitewise operations. My code can be compiled correctly. But when I run it ,and type in any value, Segementation Fault occurs. I wonder whether you may help me.

.l file

```
%}

%option noyywrap

%%
[0-9]+  {
            yylval.dval=atof(yytext);
            return INTEGER;
        }


([0-9]+|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?) {
                                               yylval.dval = atof(yytext);
                                               return NUMBER;
                                            }

[ \t    ]  ;



[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*   {
                      struct symtab *sp = symlook(yytext);
                      yylval.dval = 0.0;
                      return NAME;
                   }

"**"    {
    return POW;
    }

"<<"    {
    return LSHIFT;
    }

">>"    {
    return RSHIFT;
    }

"$"      { return 0; }

\n    |
.     return yytext[0];
%%
```

.h file

```
    #define NSYMS 20

struct symtab {
  char *name;
  double (*funcptr)();
  double dval;
  enum constype {integer, floatingpoint} constype;
} symtab[NSYMS];


struct symtab *symlook();
```

.y file

```
%{ 
#include "zcalc.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int flag = 0;

void yyerror( char *mesg ); /* yacc error checker */

%}

%union {
  double dval;
  struct symtab *symp;
}

%token <symp> NAME
%token <dval> NUMBER
%token <dval> INTEGER
%token POW
%token LSHIFT
%token RSHIFT

%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'

%type <symp> expression
%%

statement_list: statement '\n'
            | statement_list statement '\n'

    statement: NAME '=' expression {$1->dval = $3->dval;
                            if($3-                 >constype==integer)
                                $1-            >constype=integer;
                            else
                                $1-           >constype=floatingpoint;}
            | expression { printf("= %g\n", $1->dval); }

 expression: '+' expression expression { $$->dval = $2->dval + $3->dval; 
                                    if($2->constype==integer && $3->constype)
                                        $$->constype=integer;
                                    else $$->constype=floatingpoint;
                                    }
        | '-' expression expression { $$->dval = $2->dval - $3->dval; 
                                        if($2->constype==integer && $3->constype)
                                        $$->constype=integer;
                                    else $$->constype=floatingpoint;}
        | '*' expression expression { $$->dval = $2->dval * $3->dval; 
                                        if($2->constype==integer && $3->constype)
                                        $$->constype=integer;
                                    else $$->constype=floatingpoint;}
        | '/' expression expression { $$->dval = $2->dval / $3->dval;
                                        if($2->constype==integer && $3->constype)
                                        $$->constype=integer;
                                    else $$->constype=floatingpoint;}
        | '(' expression ')' { $$->dval = $2->dval; 
                                        if($2->constype==integer)
                                        $$->constype=integer;
                                    else $$->constype=floatingpoint;}
        | '&' expression expression { 
                                        if($2->constype!=integer||$3->constype!=integer)
                                        $$->dval = (int)($2->dval) & (int)($3->dval);
                                        else
                                        printf("Error: bitewise operations cannot be done to floating point vals./n")}
        | '|' expression expression { 
                                        if($2->constype!=integer||$3->constype!=integer)
                                        $$->dval = (int)($2->dval) | (int)($3->dval);
                                        else
                                        printf("Error: bitewise operations cannot be done to floating point values./n")}
        | '^' expression expression { 
                                        if($2->constype!=integer||$3->constype!=integer)
                                        $$->dval = (int)($2->dval) ^ (int)($3->dval);
                                        else
                                        printf("Error: bitewise operations cannot be done to floating point values./n")}
        | '~' expression { 
                                        if($2->constype!=integer)
                                        $$->dval = ~(int)($2->dval);
                                        else
                                        printf("Error: bitewise operations cannot be done to floating point values./n")}
        | LSHIFT expression expression { 
                                        if($2->constype!=integer||$3->constype!=integer)
                                        $$->dval = (int)$2->dval << (int)$3->dval;
                                        else
                                        printf("Error: bitewise operations cannot be done to floating point values./n")}
        | RSHIFT expression expression { 
                                        if($2->constype!=integer||$3->constype!=integer)
                                        $$->dval = (int)$2->dval >> (int)$3->dval;
                                        else
                                        printf("Error: bitewise operations cannot be done to floating point values./n")}    
        | POW   expression expression { $$->dval=pow($2->dval,$3->dval);}
        | NUMBER {$$->dval=$<dval>1;
                $$->constype=floatingpoint;
                 }
        | INTEGER {
                $$->dval=$<dval>1;
                    $$->constype=integer;}
        | NAME {
                $$->dval = $1->dval;
                if($1->constype==integer )
                    $$->constype=integer;
                else $$->constype=floatingpoint;}
 %%

 struct symtab * symlook( char *s ) {
    char *p;
    struct symtab *sp;

    for(sp = symtab; sp < &symtab[NSYMS]; sp++) {
      /* is it already here? */
 if (sp->name && !strcmp(sp->name, s))
   return sp;

 /* is it free */
 if (!sp->name) {
   sp->name = strdup(s);
   return sp;
 }
      /* otherwise continue to the next */
    }
    yyerror("Too many symbols...\n");
    exit(1);
 }

 void addfunc( char *name, double (*func)() ) {
   struct symtab *sp = symlook(name);
   sp->funcptr = func;
 }


 /* yacc error function */
 void yyerror( char *mesg ) {
       flag = 1;
       printf("%s \n" , mesg);  
     }


int main() {

  yyparse();

  return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: and what debugging have you done?

Comment: Unless symlook() returns a pointer to newly allocated memory (_not_ a local variable in the function!) this will probably crash. Just seeing parts of the program doesn't help in debugging. Find out _where_ it crashes, and _why_.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared the token `NAME` as having type `symp` but in your flex file, when you return `NAME` you are setting `yylval->dval`. You create a `symb` pointer (I presume) in `sp` but you never assign that to `yylval->sp`.

You're probably confusing yourself by using `dval` both as a `symbol` data member and as a tag for `yylval`. (At least, you confused me that way). At any rate, I'd suggest:

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*   {
                         yylval.symp = symlook(yytext);
                         return NAME;
                       }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, this code is built based on other's code. And in that code , this part is
    [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*   {
                          struct symtab *sp = symlook(yytext);
                          yylval.symp = sp;
                          return NAME;
                       }
And in the original .c file, one of the rule is 
    expression:NAME { $$ = $1->value; }(%type <dval> expression)
First, I do not quite understand why here the type of the return value is different from that of the "expression", but the original code still works.

Comment: @KuangLu: Setting yylval.symp is correct. Setting yylval.dval is incorrect (and will lead to a segfault). (In the case that the token is declared to be a `symp`). The `%type` declaration, and the `%token <tag>` declaration, do not actually declare a type; they declare a tag in the union (which has an associated type). `bison` knows what type (tag) every stack value is, but `flex` does not; so the `flex` action needs to specify the correct union member.